# How to access GUI elements in a dynamic user interface

Tags: button, javafx

I am trying to develop a dynamic user interface. When the user clicks at a certain indicator a graph of it is instantiated together with some manipulation buttons. See the image for an example. The graph is created in an HBox, together with the buttons and next added to a VBox. The problem I cannot solve is: when a button is clicked, how can I access the corresponding element?

The problem simply boils down to this:

```
  Button buttonRemove = new Button ();
  buttonRemove.setMinWidth (80);
  buttonRemove.setText ("Remove");
  buttonMap.getProperties ().put ("--IndicatorRemoveButton", indicator.getName ());
  buttonRemove.setOnAction (e -> buttonRemoveClick ());

   private Object buttonRemoveClick ()
   {
      // Which button clicked me??

      return null;
   } /*** buttonRemoveClick ***/
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm kind of stuck  with this.

[image: Example of dynamic interface].

Comment: In your code after you create the button dynamically, add a button.setOnAction event handler.

Comment: That's what I do now as you can see in the code. Do you mean I have to do something different with what I am doing now?

Comment: What do you mean when you say element?

Comment: Are you trying to find out which button did the clicking?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the graph when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to pass a parameter to the `buttonRemoveClick` method in the lambda, as long as it's effectively final or a parameter.

```
private void buttonRemoveClick (HBox group) {...}
```

```
buttonRemove.setOnAction (e -> buttonRemoveClick (theGroup));
```

---

In this case you could also pass the `ActionEvent` and get the source to retrieve the `Button`; this may not be enough to remove the element, but for this you could traverse to the parent until you reach a child of the `HBox`

```
private void buttonRemoveClick (ActionEvent event) {
    Node currentNode = (Node) event.getSource(); // this is the button

    // traverse to HBox of container
    Node p;
    while ((p = currentNode.getParent()) != containerVBox) {
        currentNode = p;
    }
    // remove part including the Button from container
    containerVBox.getChildren().remove(currentNode);
}
```

```
buttonRemove.setOnAction (this::buttonRemoveClick);
```

Comment: You saved my day! I used your second method and that works great. When creating the HBox containing the button, I provide information in a property to the button to identify it. I saw this solution described before but couldn't get it to work, so thanks a lot for your clear description!